# Write 301 Redirect pattern for many similar URLS

Tags: php, .htaccess, magento, redirect

I have many products that have been disabled in Magento store and all the links are now 404s.

I'm looking to write .htaccess rules and patterns that will apply to many similar products.

For example, I'd like to create one redirect rule for all the following products:

```
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered/cambridge.html    
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered-inset-panel-doors/danish.html 
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered/malibu.html
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered/andrea.html   
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered/stanford.html 
doors/drawer-front-styles/mitered/nantucket.html
```

Is this possible? If so, please advise.  Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: where would the URLs redirect too?

Comment: they are disabled product, so they would redirect to a category page.  Assume something like, http://www.mywebsite.com/category-1